# ssh doesnot work with wifi but work fine with wired connection

Tags: wireless, ssh

I have Ubuntu 13.10.

I use ssh to connect to a remote computer in the university using `ssh xxxx@ws.hpc.unipg.it`. It is working fine when I am using wired connection but when I try to connect through wifi using the same command it doesn’t work and gives me this error :

```
ssh: connect to host ws.hpc.unipg.it port 22: No route to host
```

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: When you're connected to WiFi, can you access the internet? Give us some context on the difference between the WiFi and wired connection. For example, are both at your home? Or is the WiFi somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you don't have internet in your wifi (or at least, that host isn't accessible from your wifi). So, how to diagnostics? You can use ping and nmap, but let me tell you, apparently that host isn't public available:

```
ping -c2 ws.hpc.unipg.it
PING ws.hpc.unipg.it (141.250.16.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- ws.hpc.unipg.it ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms
```

Here it said that the host didn't asnwer my pings

```
nmap -p22 ws.hpc.unipg.it

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-22 11:10 AST
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing Connect Scan
Connect Scan Timing: About 50.00% done; ETC: 11:10 (0:00:01 remaining)
Nmap scan report for ws.hpc.unipg.it (141.250.16.254)
Host is up (0.19s latency).
rDNS record for 141.250.16.254: gw.hpc.unipg.it
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.34 seconds
```

Here it says that the port is filtered (it could be dropping my packets), hence is very likely I can't connect. When I try to connect, it will timeout my request. So, how to solve this? **Contact your system administrator for guidance**.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is the laptop probably has a different MAC address for each network, or at least for public networks outside your own. You can usually change this in the settings for each network to use your real MAC address instead of a random one.

This might matter because you may be verified by your mac address on the remote computer. I'm not sure from that error message if this could be the case, but it's worth knowing. On my local LAN, I ssh into a server, and the key generated for it was done when it was on a wired network. Now, I'm using wireless, and that key no longer works. I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wifi is working, this probably means the ssh port is blocked on the wifi network. Or possibly that there is a firewall in front of the server which doesn't recognise the wifi IP addresses as valid.

It's possible that you are on some kind of guest wifi network, and you might be able to get better access by registering for another wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your wifi connection has a firewall blocking port 22.

Anyway, there are good chances that you can succeed using port 443.

First, test that you can use port 443 to connect via ssh

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

If you can connect to GitHub p 443, means the WIFI firewall is not blocking port 443, and you should try connecting to your university server at port 443.

```
$ ssh -p 443 xxxx@ws.hpc.unipg.it
```

If this does not work, means the server **ws.hpc.unipg.it** does not support the port 443 for ssh connections.

In this case, **if you have server access**, you should **edit the ssh configuration to allow ssh connections on port 443**:

- edit the file sshd_config  `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Uncomment the line `#Port 22` and transform it into `Port 443`.
- restart ssh service with `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

And then, you can connect :)

***Notes***:

- If you cannot connect to github which is known to respond on port 443, then your WIFI firewall blocks also port 443, and you need to go for another solution, like using a VPN.
- In case you cannot connect to server's port 443, and you have no control, ask the admin how to connect to port 443.